# Clean list from stopwords

Tags: python, nltk

This variable:

```
sent=[('include', 'details', 'about', 'your performance'),
('show', 'the', 'results,', 'which', 'you\'ve', 'got')]
```

needs to be clean of stopwords. 
I tried with

```
output = [w for w in sent if not w in stop_words]
```

but it has not worked.
What is it wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords

stop_words = {w.lower() for w in stopwords.words('english')}

sent = [('include', 'details', 'about', 'your', 'performance'),
        ('show', 'the', 'results,', 'which', 'you\'ve', 'got')]
```

If you want to create a single list of words without the stop words;

```
>>> no_stop_words = [word for sentence in sent for word in sentence if word not in stop_words]
['include', 'details', 'performance', 'show', 'results,', 'got']
```

If you want to keep the sentences intact;

```
>>> sent_no_stop = [[word for word in sentence if word not in stop_words] for sentence in sent]
[['include', 'details', 'performance'], ['show', 'results,', 'got']]
```

However, most of the time you would work with a list of words (without parentheses);

```
sent = ['include', 'details', 'about', 'your performance','show', 'the', 'results,', 'which', 'you\'ve', 'got']

>>> no_stopwords = [word for word in sent if word not in stop_words]
['include', 'details', 'performance', 'show', 'results,', 'got']
```

Comment: Note that for any non-trivial sizes, ``stop_words`` should be a ``set`` instead of a ``list``. Use ``stop_words = {w.lower() for w in stopwords.words('english')}`` to achieve this.

Comment: Note that a set comprehension ``{... for ... in ...}`` }will always create a set, even when the iterable is empty. Only a dict comprehension ``{...: ... for ... in ...}`` will create a dict.

Answer (score 6):

It's the round brackets that are getting in the way of the iteration. If you can remove them:

```
sent=['include', 'details', 'about', 'your performance','show', 'the', 'results,', 'which', 'you\'ve', 'got']
output = [w for w in sent if not w in stopwords]
```

If not, then you can do this:

```
sent=[('include', 'details', 'about', 'your performance'),('show', 'the', 'results,', 'which', 'you\'ve', 'got')]
output = [i for s in [[w for w in l if w not in stopwords] for l in sent] for i in s]
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you missing a a quote in your actual code? Make sure to close all the strings and escape your apostrophes with a backslash if you're using the same type of quote. I would also make every word separate, like this:

```
sent=[('include', 'details', 'about', 'your', 'performance'), ('show', 'the', 'results,', 'which', 'you\'ve', 'got')]
```